# Update dialog box data when user add or edit

Tags: php, jquery

I have dialog box which I load list of groups. each group can edit /delete. and bottom new groups also can added.

both group list and add group option are in same form, I want to update the group list whenever user add a group or edit list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your AJAX code correctly, But here is the shell of the idea of what you want.

First, You put your AJAX code for **`view`** inside a fucntion like

```
function view() {
 //AJAX Request for `SELECT SQL Query` PHP Page
}
```

then you do your `onclick functionality` normally as you did and put the function inside of it.

```
$("#id-selector-for-delete").click(function(){
    function view() {
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: "??",
            data: {??},
            success: function (data) {
              //JQuery HTML Attribute.
            }
        });
    }


   //AJAX Request for `DELETE SQL Query` PHP Page
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "??",
        data: {??},
        success: function (data) {
               view()  //Calling the AJAX view functionality again after deletion success.
    }

});
```

Comment: on my ajax "json_obj['usergroup'];" this returns SELECT query results from sql. I'm struggling how to append those data to my current foreach ? and in your code how I show the results return in view() function on my php